# Plaid onSuccessCallback is not calling android java

Tags: java, android, plaid

I am integrating plaid Android SDK in java. I created the link token from server and I am able to select the banks and have entered the credentials. But I am not receiving the onsuccess callback to get the public token.

my code

```
 LinkLogLevel logLevel = BuildConfig.DEBUG ? LinkLogLevel.VERBOSE : LinkLogLevel.ERROR;
                            Plaid.create(
                                  mActivity.getApplication(),
                                    new LinkTokenConfiguration.Builder()
                                            .token(getoken)
                                            .logLevel(logLevel)
                                            .build())
                                    .open(mActivity);

 private final LinkResultHandler myPlaidResultHandler = new LinkResultHandler(
            linkSuccess -> {
                String publicToken = linkSuccess.getPublicToken();
                System.out.println("publictoken"+publicToken);
                Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, HomePage.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(i);
                return Unit.INSTANCE;
            },
            linkExit -> {

                LinkError error = linkExit.getError();
                String errorCode = String.valueOf(error.getErrorCode());
                String errorMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
                String displayMessage = error.getDisplayMessage();
                LinkExitMetadata metadata = linkExit.getMetadata();
                String institutionId = metadata.getInstitution().getId();
                String institutionName = metadata.getInstitution().getName();
                String linkSessionId = metadata.getLinkSessionId();
                String requestId = metadata.getRequestId();
                System.out.println("errorMessage"+errorMessage);
                return Unit.INSTANCE;
            }

    );

 private void setOptionalEventListener() {
        Plaid.setLinkEventListener(linkEvent -> {
            Log.v("EventList", linkEvent.toString());
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you're running into this.  If you aren't able to figure this out via stepping through the app to see what the logic flow is, can you file a support ticket with Plaid?  Support can access logs that are very helpful for figuring out what's happening.